# Xamarin Forms Navigation without animation

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have an app where I want to show page A, from which the user can navigate to page B or C, from B back to A or to C, and from C only back to A, even if the user when through B to get to C
[image: Pages Navigation]

Currently when I'm executing the B->C transition I first `PopAsync` to get back to A and then I do `PushAsync` to get to C, so that the '

The question is: is there a civilized way to set up this navigation scheme while still relying on the built-in Navigation to keep track of navigation stack - I don't want to do that myself and use `PushModalAsync`.

Note that (as reflected in the image) A and C aren't the end points of the whole navigation stack, there are pages before A and after C, so the stack has to be preserved.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

On iOS the `NavigationRenderer` has virtual methods `OnPopViewAsync` and `OnPushAsync` (similar [on Android](http://www.snip2code.com/Snippet/135177/Remove-default-animation-from-Xamarin-fo)):

```cs
protected override Task<bool> OnPopViewAsync(Page page, bool animated)
{
    return base.OnPopViewAsync(page, animated);
}

protected override Task<bool> OnPushAsync(Page page, bool animated)
{
    return base.OnPushAsync(page, animated);
}
```

They call the corresponding base method with two arguments, the page and whether to animate the transition. Thus, you might be able to enable or disable the animation using the following approach:

1. Derive a custom navigation page.
2. Add an "Animated" property.
3. Derive a custom navigation renderer for your custom navigation page.
4. Override the pop and push methods calling their base methods with the "Animated" property.

Note that I haven't tried this approach, yet, since it is quite some work to do. But disabling animations on all navigation pages did work this way.

---

**Edit:** It took me several hours to actually implement my solution for my own project. Therefore, I'll share some more details. (I developed and tested on Xamarin.Forms 1.2.3-pre4.)

### The custom navigation page

Besides the above-mentioned `Animated` property my navigation page re-implements the two transition functions and adds an optional argument `animated`, which is `true` by default. This way we'll be able to keep all existing code and only add a `false` where needed.

Furthermore, both method will sleep for a very short time (10 ms) after pushing/popping the page. Without this delay we'd ran into trouble with consecutive calls.

```cs
public class CustomNavigationPage: NavigationPage
{
    public bool Animated { get; private set; }

    public CustomNavigationPage(Page page) : base(page)
    {
    }

    // Analysis disable once MethodOverloadWithOptionalParameter
    public async Task PushAsync(Page page, bool animated = true)
    {
        Animated = animated;
        await base.PushAsync(page);
        await Task.Run(delegate {
            Thread.Sleep(10);
        });
    }

    // Analysis disable once MethodOverloadWithOptionalParameter
    public async Task<Page> PopAsync(bool animated = true)
    {
        Animated = animated;
        var task = await base.PopAsync();
        await Task.Run(delegate {
            Thread.Sleep(10);
        });
        return task;
    }
}
```

### The custom navigation renderer

The renderer for my custom navigation page overrides both transition methods and passes the `Animated` property to their base methods. (It's kind of ugly to inject a flag this way, but I couldn't find a better solution.)

```cs
public class CustomNavigationRenderer: NavigationRenderer
{
    protected override Task<bool> OnPopViewAsync(Page page, bool animated)
    {
        return base.OnPopViewAsync(page, (Element as CustomNavigationPage).Animated);
    }

    protected override Task<bool> OnPushAsync(Page page, bool animated)
    {
        return base.OnPushAsync(page, (Element as CustomNavigationPage).Animated);
    }
}
```

This is for iOS. But on Android it's almost identically.

### An example application

To demonstrate the possibilities of consecutively pushing and popping pages, I wrote the following application.

The `App` class simply creates a new `DemoPage` wrapped into a `CustomNavigationPage`. Note that this instance must be publicly accessible for this example.

```cs
public static class App
{
    public static CustomNavigationPage NavigationPage;

    public static Page GetMainPage()
    {    
        return NavigationPage = new CustomNavigationPage(new DemoPage("Root"));
    }
}
```

The demo page contains a number of buttons that push and pop pages in different orders. You can add or remove the `false` option for each call to `PushAsync` or `PopAsync`.

```cs
public class DemoPage: ContentPage
{
    public DemoPage(string title)
    {
        Title = title;
        Content = new StackLayout {
            Children = {
                new Button {
                    Text = "Push",
                    Command = new Command(o => App.NavigationPage.PushAsync(new DemoPage("Pushed"))),
                },
                new Button {
                    Text = "Pop",
                    Command = new Command(o => App.NavigationPage.PopAsync()),
                },
                new Button {
                    Text = "Push + Pop",
                    Command = new Command(async o => {
                        await App.NavigationPage.PushAsync(new DemoPage("Pushed (will pop immediately)"));
                        await App.NavigationPage.PopAsync();
                    }),
                },
                new Button {
                    Text = "Pop + Push",
                    Command = new Command(async o => {
                        await App.NavigationPage.PopAsync(false);
                        await App.NavigationPage.PushAsync(new DemoPage("Popped and pushed immediately"));
                    }),
                },
                new Button {
                    Text = "Push twice",
                    Command = new Command(async o => {
                        await App.NavigationPage.PushAsync(new DemoPage("Pushed (1/2)"), false);
                        await App.NavigationPage.PushAsync(new DemoPage("Pushed (2/2)"));
                    }),
                },
                new Button {
                    Text = "Pop twice",
                    Command = new Command(async o => {
                        await App.NavigationPage.PopAsync(false);
                        await App.NavigationPage.PopAsync();
                    }),
                },
            },
        };
    }
}
```

**Important hint:** It cost me hours of debugging to find out that you need to use an instance of `NavigationPage` (or a derivative) rather than the `ContentPage`'s `Navigation`! Otherwise the immediate call of two or more pops or pushes leads to strange behaviour and crashes.

Comment: I can not add Thread.Sleep(10). it can not find it. What is a problem?

Comment: @AEMLoviji: I'm `using System.Threading` to get the method `Thread.Sleep`.

Comment: I know that Thread.Sleep contains in System.Threadin. But in Xamarin Project i can not see it...

Comment: Maybe you should use async () => await Task.Delay(10) instead of Thread.Sleep(10) because Thread.Sleep (to my knowledge) does not guarantee to wait on the correct thread.

Answer (score 5):

@Falko 
You now have the possibility to include a boolean parameter:

```
 Navigation.PushAsync (new Page2Xaml (), false);
```

[Xamarin Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/navigation/modal#animating-page-transitions)

Comment: Is there also a global setting that would also affect e.g. navigation on back press?

Answer (score 0):

Currently the Xamarin Forms navigation is very spartanic and I doubt there is a nice way to achieve that. Besides Doing and extra "Pop" when necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a collection of snippets I whipped together along with some other niceties to improve NaviagationPage for iOS. [Link to comment and code on xamarin forums.](http://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/comment/82404/#Comment_82404)

Answer (score 0):

What I would do if I were doing this is push Page C on to your NavigationStack and then take page B off of the stack. That way when you pop from page C, you would go to page A.

```
// Push the page you want to go to on top of the stack.    
await NavigationPage.PushAsync(new CPage()));

// Remove page B from the stack, so when you want to go back next time 
//you will go to page A.   
Navigation.RemovePage(Navigation.NavigationStack[Navigation.NavigationStack.Count - 2] );
```

Alternatively, when even you pop from page C, you could remove all instances of type page B from the stack, and then pop back 1. In that case, page B would remain on the stack until you were about to move back from page C to page A.

Comment: RemovePage seems to be a public method, however, I was experiencing strange exceptions in the past (NullReferenceException in some renderers on Xamarin iOS) in the past. Be careful!