# Xamarin Forms Custom PopAsync Close Animation

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

Follow this [question & answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63505140/animate-page-from-right-to-left-or-left-to-right) I have created a new `PageRenderer` for `PushAsync` or `PushModelAsync` works perfect. I would like to make the same animation for `PopAsync` as the method has a `boolean` overload for animation [Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/xamarin.forms.navigationpage.popasync?view=xamarin-forms). I've done the research and I cannot find anything to do with creating custom animation for this method.

I'm currently only working on `Android` Solution.

Is it possible? Because currently I have a nice animation for Pushing pages but once I want to get rid of them is just `POP` as it says in the method name.

**Update**: I found out that with the same override method `OnAttachedToWindow` to create an `PushAsync` animation there is an opposite override `OnDetachedFromWindow` but the screen disappears before the animation code is executed.

I've added a break point onto the Attached method and Detached and the code does pause at the Detached when `PopAsync` is executed but no amination comes through. Could this be a `BUG`? or is it the actual implementation that is happening under the hood of `PopAsync`.

**Code**

```
protected override void OnDetachedFromWindow()
{
    var myValue = Preferences.Get("ModelAnimationDetach", false);
    if (myValue)
    {
        var metrics = Resources.DisplayMetrics;
        Android.Views.Animations.Animation translateAnimation = new TranslateAnimation(0, metrics.HeightPixels, 0, 0)
        {
            Duration = 2000
        };
        Animation = translateAnimation;
        translateAnimation.Start();
    }

    base.OnDetachedFromWindow();
}
```

Many Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `Shell` template to develop the application, the navigation in the Shell has this `animation` style.

For more information, you can check doc: [navigation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/shell/navigation).

If you don't want to use the shell template, you can try to create the custom NavigationPage renderer to customize the transaction style on each platform.

For this, you can check [Xamarin Forms Navigation without animation](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25944224/).

You can also check article [Animating Page Transitions in Xamarin Forms](https://xamgirl.com/animating-page-transitions-in-xamarin-forms/).